# Omit null arguments when calling a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm calling a cmdlet on the basis of various input parameters. Most of those parameters are optional and could resolve to null, in which case I want to omit the corresponding cmdlet argument. Is there a better way than this to do this:

```
$var1 = ...;
$var2 = ...;
$var3 = ...;

if($var1 -and $var2 -and $var3) {
  My-Cmdlet -Var1 $var1 -Var2 $var2 -Var3 $var
} else if($var1 -and $var2) {
  My-Cmdlet -Var1 $var1 -Var2 $var2
} else if($var2 -and $var3) {
 ...
}
...
```

That can't be it?!

Comment: Splat it. `$args = @{}; if ($var1) { $args["var1"] = $var1 }; ... My-Cmdlet @args`. The check-for-null-and-add-if-not thing can be refined with script blocks if necessary (or just a little helper method).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Since `$args` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args), I'd suggest to use another name for that.